# alternate fullcalendar row background color by week

Tags: css, fullcalendar

([I check this post already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330924/is-it-possible-to-do-alternating-row-background-colours-in-fullcalendar) )
I try to alternate the week background color from fullcalendar, I try a lot of it, but it changes all my background or just change the event background only.
I use chrome inspect tools and see they use the table, but each table doesn't have a class name.

//Here's the code I try:

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #CCC
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background: #FFF
}
```

Up there code only change my event content background color, not the whole week row background.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: which view type are we talking about? agenda? month? list? timeline? The markup is entirely different in each case.

Comment: Hi ADyson, Thank you for the response, just regular month views, with events on it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `nth-child`, use `nth-of-type`.

Also, you need to target the series of `<div>` elements which represent the rows - they are not a table. They're inside a table, and there are more tables inside them, but the rows themselves are actually `<div>`s (you can see this when you inspect the rendered HTML of the calendar using your browser tools).

```
.fc-day-grid > div.fc-row:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/66/ for a working demo.

Credit to this answer: [CSS div alternating colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004537/css-div-alternating-colour) for providing a generic example of alternating colours on `divs` - effectively this solution is not specific to fullCalendar, it's specific to the structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For the @fullcalendar angular implementation, you can achieve this by using this selector

```
.fc-timegrid-slots tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```